Can an overhead vented hood be connected to an island intake vent?0
I have an electric stovetop on an island with a vent to the rear of the stovetop that is not visible when off. When turned on, it rises up behind the stovetop- seemed cool at the time. The vent intake is to the side (back side) of the stovetop, and it doesn’t rise up even as high as a typical pot, so you can imagine how effective that is. The down-drafted vent runs through the slab out through an exterior wall. We’ve had to replaced this nifty little vent twice already, and this time we want an overhead exhaust vent. The island does have power, and the only thing over the island is a light fixture on the ceiling. Can an overhead exhaust vent be connected to the downdraft vent that already exists and exits through the slab?

yes it can be used

I'm not getting your intent.  Are you wanting to add an island hood from the ceiling, and connect its duct down to the floor, instead of running it across the ceiling?

Yes, that was the intent.  Just as an option to save money.  In the long run, I don't think it would actually save money.

Yes you can do that... it will probably look kind of industrial.
I would be investigating which way the ceiling joists run and whether it's possibl;e to slip a duct in there from the outside to a place over the cooktop.  in other words: the boring conventional solution.

It all depends what level of DIY are you.
The downdraft exhaust runs under the floor. The overhead vent runs above the ceiling.
Where you will connect them depends,

I would be connecting the ducts inside the island.  It was just an option I was looking in to.  I don't think that's what we'll do, though.  Thanks
